# Is dropdown list opened or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list in my webpage using asp.net and c#. My question is how can I know this dropdown is opened or not. I don't want to mean selected or focused. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible only with client side code.. what is your bigger goal here? When do you want to know this and what you want to do with the information exactly?

Comment: Thanks you for your attention, my aim is to set down arrow key. When this dropdown is closed and press down arrow key , then I focus next control. When dropdown is opened and press down arrow key, then select the item of dropdown list. So I want to know whether dropdown is opened or not.

Comment: I think you mean "focused", not "opened" so [TJHeuvel answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896180/is-dropdown-list-opened-or-not/6896230#6896230) is what you need.

Comment: I don't wanna mean "focused" , I mean "opened" , but now I think that I am OK with TJHeuvel's answer . But not sure . Now I am trying . I also deeply thanks you for your answer

Comment: It doesn't have to be "opened", when focused and still closed, pressing up/down arrows will change the selection of the drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript you have the [OnFocus](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp) event.

Comment: Is the dropdown always *opened* when it has the focus? When I select something in a dropdown and then happen to use the scrollwheel, the value changes without showing the full list.

Comment: There are probably many ways to focus the element, without opening it. However it is most common it will open in any regular browser, not on a mobile device.
You could check the calculated height of the element to check if its open i guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Now I am trying to check the height of the element.

Answer (score -1):

You can get drop down selected value using below JS code

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Thats not the question, he wants to know if its folded open or not.